UML StringExpressions, Operands and SubExpressions
In the latest UML specification for 2.5.1, the implementation in the OCL language of the overridden StringExpression::stringValue() is given at section 8.6.17.5 "Operations" on page 130:

body: if subExpression->notEmpty() then subExpression->iterate(se;
stringValue: String = '' | stringValue.concat(se.stringValue())) else
operand->iterate(op; stringValue: String = '' |
stringValue.concat(op.stringValue())) endif

The intent of this is perfectly clear; however, for example in specifying an ordered list of function parameters, there is always some kind of separator token (usually the comma) to delimit the individual arguments passed to a function. AFAICT the OCL 'concat' operation does not supply any separator token.
Since theoretically a StringExpression's subexpressions might return their own concatenated subexpressions, ending up with some kind of nesting of operands, it seems that no separator at all would quickly lead to confusion and errors.
It doesn't seem to be specified anywhere as to whether the concatenated operands or subexpressions need to be separated by commas or perhaps some other token? There might be languages in use where something other than the comma is used (perhaps a space?), so it is conceivable that the behavior could be overridden by a Profile in some form or fashion.
Is this a defect in the specification?

It is not clear why you expect the result of evaluating an expression to result in something which allows reconstruction of the terms of that expression.

@PeteKirkham: Please refer to section 8.3.3.2, String Expressions: (...) "StringExpressions are intended to be used to specify the names of NamedElements in the context of Templates." They are not evaluated, simply used to name a template.And usually the formal or actual parameters of a template are separated by a comma.

I don't know what you could call calculating the result of stringValue() if not evaluating the string expression, but anyway.  If you need separators in the result, then you would put them into the expression, just like any other programming language. (well, a bit more awkwardly as you can't mix expressions and literals within an expression). UML does not know which separators you want in your naming convention, so it can't do that for you.

@PeteKirkham: Yes, it would be trivial to concatenate the subexpressions using a different implementation with commas separating them. However, my question pertains more to the OCL implementation given -- which, if executed faithfully, apparently would NOT insert any separator between the subexpressions. I am wondering if any UML tools actually implement the StringExpression::stringValue() operator this way, or if commas are simply thrown in by the tool's implementation, bypassing stringValue() completely? The OCL implementation is also part of the UML specification, after all.

From my experience OCL is still more on an academic level. Tools are rare and I don't know any on a non-educational level (I'm retired and have not investigated in a recent past).

OCL concat doesn't add any separators, but this no problem for stringValue since it doesn't need them. As you can see in figure 7.6 StringExpressions are mainly used to name elements that are created by binding a TemplateParameter to a LiteralString. If you want to include a separator, you can do it in the specification of the nameExpression (e.g. $foo, <Resource>, <ResourceKind>, ba$).
By the way, I tried to replicate the diagram in figure 7.6, but it seems that my tool doesn't completely support templates and name expressions. It's very likely that other tools will also fail. Seems this part of the specification has been neglected by the tool vendors.


stringValue() is clearly documented in 8.6.17.5 to just concatenate and as you have observed that is exactly what it does.
You are right that a more re-useable implementation would supply at least a space separator to avoid confusing concatenations.
The implementation can be made more readable with the String::+ operator.
iterate(se; acc: String = '' |
   if acc.isEmpty() then se.stringValue() else acc + ',' + se.stringValue() endif)

A String::splice operation would be even better.
